# Compiler error while trying to run vs 2012 website on local iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

While trying to run a Visual Studio 2012 website on local iis I receive the following in the browser after a successful build.

> Compilation Error  Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code
>   -1073741511.
>
> Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>   c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe"
>   /t:library /utf8output ...
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.81.0  1073741511

What could be causing this?

Comment: The error indicates a problem with the compiler itself, rather than your code.  Maybe your install is broken somehow.  Try the same code on another box.

Comment: This can be caused by incorrect dll version being referenced by your app (usually when you are referencing older versions of a required DLL), or it could be because you have a required DLL missing from the bin folder. P.S. If at compile you put dlls (Copy Local set to true) in your bin, and you alter those references make sure you delete the old dlls from the bin folder.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your comments. I'm going to try your recommendations and I'll comment later on the results.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem came from both of the comments above. I repaired the installation using isos for VS2012 and update 5. And, there was an incorrect dll version. I would like to give credit to antlersoft and Paul Zahra. How do I do that?